# How to set Excel PageBreak with xlwings in python?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, page-break

Need help with setting **PageBreak** excel file with **xlwings** package in python.
According to Microsoft website: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/office/vba/api/excel.range.pagebreak

I've tried

```
app = xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
wb = app.books.open("raw_data/" + raw_file_name, update_links=False)
sht = wb.sheets['sheet1']
sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = 'xlPageBreakManual' # I would like to set on row 24
```

and the program stuck forever. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlwings does not know what *xlPageBreakManual* is unless its referenced. Nevertheless in this case it's not necessary. The default is to add a manual Page Break therefore syntax is only; **sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = True**. If you then check the PageBreak status on row 24; **print(sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak)** it should return *-4135* which is the excel constant for *xlPageBreakManual*.

You can use the constants to set the type of PageBreak, e.g. the line **sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = True** could also be written as **sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = -4135** or **sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = PageBreak.xlPageBreakManual**

The page break values can be referenced from the xlwings constants using the syntax **from xlwings.constants import PageBreak**. My example shown below sets the page break at row 24 then shows the status of the previous, actual and ensuing rows. The previous and ensuing rows have a status of *-4142* i.e. no page break while row 24 is *-4135*.

The code then removes the page break using *xlPageBreakNone* and the three rows 23-25 are all *-4142* again.

For this test I used xlwings v0.26.1

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import PageBreak

### Constant values for reference
# xlPageBreakAutomatic = -4105
# xlPageBreakManual = -4135
# xlPageBreakNone = -4142

app = xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
sht = xw.Book("book.xlsx").sheets['Sheet1']

print("Add Page break at row 24")
sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = True
# sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = -4135  # This does the same as the line above 
# sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = PageBreak.xlPageBreakManual # As does this line
print('Row23: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(23).PageBreak))
print('Row24: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak))
print('Row25: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(25).PageBreak))

print("\nDelete Page break at row 24")
sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak = PageBreak.xlPageBreakNone
print('Row23: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(23).PageBreak))
print('Row24: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(24).PageBreak))
print('Row25: ' + str(sht.api.Rows(25).PageBreak))
```

Note attempting to manually set a page break to -4105 (xlPageBreakAutomatic) fails which I would expect.